# how to save sql value in some variable in jenkinfile pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am creating a jenkins pipeline where I want to execute a sql script then store that value to some variable as below

```
String value = sql sql: "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE id = ?", parameters: [1]
```

**Getting a error at above point java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'sql' found among steps [ArtifactoryGradleB**

then use that value to build

```
build job: 'build_Test', parameters: [validatingString(name: 'version', value: '$value'), string(name: 'TASK', value: 'build')]
```

Is this a correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that looks correct. You should remove the single quotes surrounding the variable and use double quotes instead, or just use the variable name.

```
build job: 'build_Test', parameters: [validatingString(name: 'version', value: "$value"), string(name: 'TASK', value: 'build')]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I am getting error at first line of the code where where I am executing sql script. Getting a error at above point java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'sql' found among steps [ArtifactoryGradleB

Comment: @Willingtolearn have you installed the Database plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/database/?

Comment: yes, already there